# Java: Pause thread and get position in file

Tags: java, multithreading, file, bufferedreader

I'm writing an application in Java with multithreading which I want to pause and resume.
The thread is reading a file line by line while finding matching lines to a pattern. It has to continue on the place I paused the thread. To read the file I use a BufferedReader in combination with an InputStreamReader and FileInputStream.

```
fip = new FileInputStream(new File(*file*));
fileBuffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fip));
```

I use this FileInputStream because I need the filepointer for the position in the file.
When processing the lines it writes the matching lines to a MySQL database. To use a MySQL-connection between the threads I use a ConnectionPool to make sure just one thread is using one connection.

The problem is when I pause the threads and resume them, a few matching lines just disappear. I also tried to subtract the buffersize from the offset but it still has the same problem.

What is a decent way to solve this problem or what am I doing wrong?

Some more details:

The loop

```
    // Regex engine
    RunAutomaton ra = new RunAutomaton(this.conf.getAuto(), true);
    lw = new LogWriter();

        while((line=fileBuffer.readLine()) != null) {
            if(line.length()>0) {
                if(ra.run(line)) {
                        // Write to LogWriter
                        lw.write(line, this.file.getName());
                        lw.execute();
                    }
                }
            }
            // Loop when paused.
            while(pause) { }
        }
```

Calculating place in file

```
// Get the position in the file
public long getFilePosition() throws IOException {
    long position = fip.getChannel().position() - bufferSize + fileBuffer.getNextChar();
    return position;
}
```

Putting it into the database

```
            // Get the connector
            ConnectionPoolManager cpl = ConnectionPoolManager.getManager();
            Connector con = null;
            while(con == null)
                con = cpl.getConnectionFromPool();
            // Insert the query
            con.executeUpdate(this.sql.toString());
            cpl.returnConnectionToPool(con);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the root of the problem is that you shouldn't be subtracting `bufferSize`.  Rather you should be subtracting the number of unread characters in the buffer.  And I don't think there's a way to get this.

The easiest solution I can think of is to create a custom subclass of FilterReader that keeps track of the number of characters read.  Then stack the streams as follows:

```
FileReader 
< BufferedReader 
< custom filter reader
< BufferedReader(sz == 1)
```

The final `BufferedReader` is there so that you can use readLine ... but you need to set the buffer size to 1 so that the character count from your filter matches the position that the application has reached.

Alternatively, you could implement your own `readLine()` method in the custom filter reader.

Comment: Like I said in my previous posts. I subtract the bufferSize and then I add the characters read in the buffer. This way you subtract only the number of unread characters in the buffer. There is no way to get this in the standard BufferedReader but I extended the standard BufferedReader to get the amount of characters that are already readed.

Comment: @Yoni - perhaps the problem is character counts versus byte counts.  I don't think you should be drilling down to the file channel to try and figure out what the position is.  Just count the characters at a higher level in the stack.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of what I believe you're looking for. You didn't show much of your implementation so it's hard to debug what might be causing gaps for you. Note that the position of the `FileInputStream` is going to be a multiple of 8192 because the `BufferedReader` is using a buffer of that size. If you want to use multiple threads to read the same file you might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510979/java-read-text-file-by-chunks/5511672#5511672) helpful.

```
public class ReaderThread extends Thread {
    private final FileInputStream fip;
    private final BufferedReader fileBuffer;
    private volatile boolean paused;

    public ReaderThread(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
        fip = new FileInputStream(file);
        fileBuffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fip));
    }

    public void setPaused(boolean paused) {
        this.paused = paused;
    }

    public long getFilePos() throws IOException {
        return fip.getChannel().position();
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            String line;
            while ((line = fileBuffer.readLine()) != null) {
                // process your line here
                System.out.println(line);

                while (paused) {
                    sleep(10);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // handle I/O errors
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // handle interrupt
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought it would be a multiple of 8192 so that's why I made an extended version of BufferedReader where I can read the variable nextChar so I subtract 8192 from the filepointer and add the value of nextChar to it. This example is what I currently have and it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

After a few days searching I found out that indeed subtracting the buffersize and adding the position in the buffer wasn't the right way to do it. The position was never right and I was always missing some lines.
When searching a new way to do my job I didn't count the number of characters because it are just too many characters to count which will decrease my performance a lot. But I've found something else. Software engineer Mark S. Kolich created [a class JumpToLine](http://mark.koli.ch/2010/01/java-jumptoline-jump-to-a-line-in-a-file.html) which uses the Apache IO library to jump to a given line. It can also provide the last line it has readed so this is really what I need.
There are some examples on his homepage for those interested.